# How to get correct htlatex output with lithuanian letters?

Tags: unicode, tex4ht, htlatex

My example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

ąčęėįšųūĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪžŽ

\[
\alpha + \beta = \gamma
\]

\end{document}
```

produces incorect result:

```
<p class="noindent" >ąčę÷ĮšųūĄČĘŻĮŠŲūžŽ</p>
```

when I run:

```
 htlatex test.tex "xhtml,mathml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `tex4ht` conversion table for `l7x` encoding is wrong. You can try the following table, if it works correctly, we can fix it in `tex4ht`.

Save it as `l7x-lm.htf`:

```
l7x-lm 0 254
'&#x0060;'  ''  uni0060
'&#x00B4;'  ''  uni00B4
'&#x02C6;'  ''  uni02C6
'&#x02DC;'  ''  uni02DC
'&#x00A8;'  ''  uni00A8
'&#x02DD;'  ''  uni02DD
'&#x02DA;'  ''  uni02DA
'&#x02C7;'  ''  uni02C7
'&#x02D8;'  ''  uni02D8
'&#x00AF;'  ''  uni00AF
'&#x02D9;'  ''  uni02D9
'&#x00B8;'  ''  uni00B8
'&#x02DB;'  ''  uni02DB
'&#x201A;'  ''  uni201A
'&#x2039;'  ''  uni2039
'&#x203A;'  ''  uni203A
'&#x201C;'  ''  uni201C
'&#x201D;'  ''  uni201D
'&#x201E;'  ''  uni201E
'&#x00AB;'  ''  uni00AB
'&#x00BB;'  ''  uni00BB
'&#x2013;'  ''  uni2013
'&#x2014;'  ''  uni2014
'&#xEB10;'  ''  uniEB10
'&#xEB4D;'  ''  uniEB4D
'&#x0131;'  ''  uni0131
'&#xF6BE;'  ''  uniF6BE
'&#xFB00;'  ''  uniFB00
'&#xFB01;'  ''  uniFB01
'&#xFB02;'  ''  uniFB02
'&#xFB03;'  ''  uniFB03
'&#xFB04;'  ''  uniFB04
'&#x0020;'  ''  uni0020
'&#x0021;'  ''  uni0021
'&#x0022;'  ''  uni0022
'&#x0023;'  ''  uni0023
'&#x0024;'  ''  uni0024
'&#x0025;'  ''  uni0025
'&#x0026;'  ''  uni0026
'&#x2019;'  ''  uni2019
'&#x0028;'  ''  uni0028
'&#x0029;'  ''  uni0029
'&#x002A;'  ''  uni002A
'&#x002B;'  ''  uni002B
'&#x002C;'  ''  uni002C
'&#x002D;'  ''  uni002D
'&#x002E;'  ''  uni002E
'&#x002F;'  ''  uni002F
'&#x0030;'  ''  uni0030
'&#x0031;'  ''  uni0031
'&#x0032;'  ''  uni0032
'&#x0033;'  ''  uni0033
'&#x0034;'  ''  uni0034
'&#x0035;'  ''  uni0035
'&#x0036;'  ''  uni0036
'&#x0037;'  ''  uni0037
'&#x0038;'  ''  uni0038
'&#x0039;'  ''  uni0039
'&#x003A;'  ''  uni003A
'&#x003B;'  ''  uni003B
'&#x003C;'  ''  uni003C
'&#x003D;'  ''  uni003D
'&#x003E;'  ''  uni003E
'&#x003F;'  ''  uni003F
'&#x0040;'  ''  uni0040
'&#x0041;'  ''  uni0041
'&#x0042;'  ''  uni0042
'&#x0043;'  ''  uni0043
'&#x0044;'  ''  uni0044
'&#x0045;'  ''  uni0045
'&#x0046;'  ''  uni0046
'&#x0047;'  ''  uni0047
'&#x0048;'  ''  uni0048
'&#x0049;'  ''  uni0049
'&#x004A;'  ''  uni004A
'&#x004B;'  ''  uni004B
'&#x004C;'  ''  uni004C
'&#x004D;'  ''  uni004D
'&#x004E;'  ''  uni004E
'&#x004F;'  ''  uni004F
'&#x0050;'  ''  uni0050
'&#x0051;'  ''  uni0051
'&#x0052;'  ''  uni0052
'&#x0053;'  ''  uni0053
'&#x0054;'  ''  uni0054
'&#x0055;'  ''  uni0055
'&#x0056;'  ''  uni0056
'&#x0057;'  ''  uni0057
'&#x0058;'  ''  uni0058
'&#x0059;'  ''  uni0059
'&#x005A;'  ''  uni005A
'&#x005B;'  ''  uni005B
'&#x005C;'  ''  uni005C
'&#x005D;'  ''  uni005D
'&#x005E;'  ''  uni005E
'&#x005F;'  ''  uni005F
'&#x2018;'  ''  uni2018
'&#x0061;'  ''  uni0061
'&#x0062;'  ''  uni0062
'&#x0063;'  ''  uni0063
'&#x0064;'  ''  uni0064
'&#x0065;'  ''  uni0065
'&#x0066;'  ''  uni0066
'&#x0067;'  ''  uni0067
'&#x0068;'  ''  uni0068
'&#x0069;'  ''  uni0069
'&#x006A;'  ''  uni006A
'&#x006B;'  ''  uni006B
'&#x006C;'  ''  uni006C
'&#x006D;'  ''  uni006D
'&#x006E;'  ''  uni006E
'&#x006F;'  ''  uni006F
'&#x0070;'  ''  uni0070
'&#x0071;'  ''  uni0071
'&#x0072;'  ''  uni0072
'&#x0073;'  ''  uni0073
'&#x0074;'  ''  uni0074
'&#x0075;'  ''  uni0075
'&#x0076;'  ''  uni0076
'&#x0077;'  ''  uni0077
'&#x0078;'  ''  uni0078
'&#x0079;'  ''  uni0079
'&#x007A;'  ''  uni007A
'&#x007B;'  ''  uni007B
'&#x007C;'  ''  uni007C
'&#x007D;'  ''  uni007D
'&#x007E;'  ''  uni007E
''  ''  none
'&#x20AC;'  ''  uni20AC
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x0192;'  ''  uni0192
''  ''  none
'&#x2026;'  ''  uni2026
'&#x2020;'  ''  uni2020
'&#x2021;'  ''  uni2021
''  ''  none
'&#x2030;'  ''  uni2030
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x0152;'  ''  uni0152
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2022;'  ''  uni2022
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2122;'  ''  uni2122
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x0153;'  ''  uni0153
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x00A0;'  ''  uni00A0
''  ''  none
'&#x00A2;'  ''  uni00A2
'&#x00A3;'  ''  uni00A3
'&#x00A4;'  ''  uni00A4
''  ''  none
'&#x00A6;'  ''  uni00A6
'&#x00A7;'  ''  uni00A7
'&#x00D8;'  ''  uni00D8
'&#x00A9;'  ''  uni00A9
'&#x0156;'  ''  uni0156
''  ''  none
'&#x00AC;'  ''  uni00AC
'&#xEB2F;'  ''  uniEB2F
'&#x00AE;'  ''  uni00AE
'&#x00C6;'  ''  uni00C6
'&#x00B0;'  ''  uni00B0
'&#x00B1;'  ''  uni00B1
'&#x00B2;'  ''  uni00B2
'&#x00B3;'  ''  uni00B3
''  ''  none
'&#x00B5;'  ''  uni00B5
'&#x00B6;'  ''  uni00B6
'&#x00B7;'  ''  uni00B7
'&#x00F8;'  ''  uni00F8
'&#x00B9;'  ''  uni00B9
'&#x0157;'  ''  uni0157
''  ''  none
'&#x00BC;'  ''  uni00BC
'&#x00BD;'  ''  uni00BD
'&#x00BE;'  ''  uni00BE
'&#x00E6;'  ''  uni00E6
'&#x0104;'  ''  uni0104
'&#x012E;'  ''  uni012E
'&#x0100;'  ''  uni0100
'&#x0106;'  ''  uni0106
'&#x00C4;'  ''  uni00C4
'&#x00C5;'  ''  uni00C5
'&#x0118;'  ''  uni0118
'&#x0112;'  ''  uni0112
'&#x010C;'  ''  uni010C
'&#x00C9;'  ''  uni00C9
'&#x0179;'  ''  uni0179
'&#x0116;'  ''  uni0116
'&#x0122;'  ''  uni0122
'&#x0136;'  ''  uni0136
'&#x012A;'  ''  uni012A
'&#x013B;'  ''  uni013B
'&#x0160;'  ''  uni0160
'&#x0143;'  ''  uni0143
'&#x0145;'  ''  uni0145
'&#x00D3;'  ''  uni00D3
'&#x014C;'  ''  uni014C
'&#x00D5;'  ''  uni00D5
'&#x00D6;'  ''  uni00D6
'&#x00D7;'  ''  uni00D7
'&#x0172;'  ''  uni0172
'&#x0141;'  ''  uni0141
'&#x015A;'  ''  uni015A
'&#x016A;'  ''  uni016A
'&#x00DC;'  ''  uni00DC
'&#x017B;'  ''  uni017B
'&#x017D;'  ''  uni017D
'&#x00DF;'  ''  uni00DF
'&#x0105;'  ''  uni0105
'&#x012F;'  ''  uni012F
'&#x0101;'  ''  uni0101
'&#x0107;'  ''  uni0107
'&#x00E4;'  ''  uni00E4
'&#x00E5;'  ''  uni00E5
'&#x0119;'  ''  uni0119
'&#x0113;'  ''  uni0113
'&#x010D;'  ''  uni010D
'&#x00E9;'  ''  uni00E9
'&#x017A;'  ''  uni017A
'&#x0117;'  ''  uni0117
'&#x0123;'  ''  uni0123
'&#x0137;'  ''  uni0137
'&#x012B;'  ''  uni012B
'&#x013C;'  ''  uni013C
'&#x0161;'  ''  uni0161
'&#x0144;'  ''  uni0144
'&#x0146;'  ''  uni0146
'&#x00F3;'  ''  uni00F3
'&#x014D;'  ''  uni014D
'&#x00F5;'  ''  uni00F5
'&#x00F6;'  ''  uni00F6
'&#x00F7;'  ''  uni00F7
'&#x0173;'  ''  uni0173
'&#x0142;'  ''  uni0142
'&#x015B;'  ''  uni015B
'&#x016B;'  ''  uni016B
'&#x00FC;'  ''  uni00FC
'&#x017C;'  ''  uni017C
'&#x017E;'  ''  uni017E
l7x-lm 0 254
```

You must add empty line at the end of the `htf` file, you would get an error otherwise. Stackexchange editor strips it from the code listing unfortunately.

The result with your sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I get error: `255:  l7x-lm 0 254--- error --- Improper file \`l7x-lm.htf'`

Comment: @user21710 that's strange, I don't get any error.

Comment: @user21710 try to add empty line at the end of the htf file, it was striped by stackexhange